# SQL - Conditionally joining two columns in same table into one

Tags: sql

I am working with a table that contains two versions of stored information. To simplify it, one column contains the old description of a file run while another column contains the updated standard for displaying ran files. It gets more complicated in that the older column can have multiple standards within itself. The table:

```
Old Column              New Column
Desc: LGX/101/rpt          null
  null                     Home
Print: LGX/234/rpt         null
  null                     Print
  null                     Page
```

I need to combine the two columns into one, but I also need to delete the "Print: " and "Desc: " string from the beginning of the old column values. Any suggestions? Let me know if/when I'm forgetting something you need to know!

(I am writing in Cache SQL, but I'd just like a general approach to my problem, I can figure out the specifics past that.)

EDIT: the condition is that if substr(oldcol,1,5) = 'desc: ' then substr(oldcol,6)
      else if substr(oldcol,1,6) = 'print: ' then substr(oldcol,7) etc. So as to take out the "desc: " and the "print: " to sanitize the data somewhat.

EDIT2: I want to make the table look like this:

```
    Col
  LGX/101/rpt
    Home
  LGX/234/rpt
    Print
    Page
```

Comment: In your title you say 'conditionally'. What's the condition? Also, how do you want to combine them? Concatenation?

Comment: Is one of the columns always null or is that just how it happens to be in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what you are looking for exactly. Does the above represent before/after, or both columns that need combining/merging.

My guess is that `COALESCE` might be able to help you. It takes a bunch of parameters and returns the first non NULL.

Comment: I am showing what the table looks like right now. Sorry, I will include what I want it to look like

Comment: Thanks. I stand by `COALESCE` then for the column merge. You want 

`SELECT COALESCE(NewCol, OldCol) AS Col` to merge the columns correctly.

You've already solved the stripping of the words. However, you could also use REPLACE multiple times if you don't have many words to strip out:

`SELECT COALESCE(NewCol, REPLACE(REPLACE(OldCol, "Print: ", ""), "Desc: ", "")) As Col`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're wanting to grab values from new if old is NULL and old if new is null. To do that you can use a case statement in your SQL. I know CASE statements are supported by MySQL, I'm not sure if they'll help you here.

`SELECT (CASE WHEN old_col IS NULL THEN new_col ELSE old_col END) as val FROM table_name`

This will grab new_col if old_col is NULL, otherwise it will grab old_col.

Comment: As for the removal of Desc: and Print:, you're probably better off doing that in whatever language is going to receive the result set. SQL isn't the best for string manipulation.

Comment: Stephen is right, COALESCE will do the same thing as the case statement, but it looks a lot cleaner. I'd go with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Print: and Desc: by using a combination of CharIndex and Substring functions. Here it goes

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',COALESCE(OldCol,NewCol)) > 0 THEN 
         SUBSTRING(COALESCE(OldCol,NewCol),CHARINDEX(':',COALESCE(OldCol,NewCol))+1,8000) 
         ELSE
         COALESCE(OldCol,NewCol)
        END AS Newcolvalue  
FROM  [SchemaName].[TableName]
```

The Charindex gives the position of the character/string you are searching for.

So you get the position of ":" in the computed column(Coalesce part) and pass that value to the substring function. Then add +1 to the position which indicates the substring function to get the part after the ":". Now you have a string without "Desc:" and "Print:".

Hope this helps.

Comment: MSSQL is the database that I have taken into consideration.